# Passing RMI Bean to custom class variable

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I am trying to mess up with RMI and I've got some problems. I want to use remote method in my custom class but I don't know how to pass bean to class variable. The RMI connection itself seems to work fine. My code is:

```
//Application start class

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    RmiProxyFactoryBean searchService() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiSearchServiceBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmiSearchServiceBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://127.0.0.1:1199/searchService");
        rmiSearchServiceBean.setServiceInterface(SearchService.class);
        return rmiSearchServiceBean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}


@Component
public class RmiSearchContext {

    @Bean
    RmiProxyFactoryBean searchService() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiSearchServiceBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmiSearchServiceBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://127.0.0.1:1199/searchService");
        rmiSearchServiceBean.setServiceInterface(SearchService.class);
        return rmiSearchServiceBean;
    }

}


//My custom class where I want to make remote method call
@Component
public class BasicSearchQuery {

    private long id;
    private String content;
    //This is a variable for the Bean
    @Autowared
    private SearchService searchService; 

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public SearchService getSearchService() {
        return this.searchService;
    }

    public void  setSearchService(SearchService searchService) {
        this.searchService = searchService;
    }

    public List<BasicSearchResults> execute() {
        // Here i want to do a remote method call
        return this.searchService.getSearchResults(this.id, this.content));
    }

}
```

Is there any way to do that without using context.xml files?

Comment: add @Autowired annotation to `private SearchService searchService;`, that should be enough.

Comment: @user1516873, unfortunatelly it doesnt work for me.I tried this before posting the question and here is the message: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.SearchService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency`

Comment: it means `BasicSearchQuery` not picked up when spring do `ComponentScan`. Try to set correct base package name, for example @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org"}). You really put your classes in "org" package? Don't do that. Use Sun [recommendations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for package naming.

Comment: @user1516873, Ok, I moved RMI bean to standalone class and it looks like `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` has gone and `@Autowired` is working. Now I am getting `NullPointerException` error while calling remote method. Also I can get the bean from `Application.class` context, but not from `BasicSearchQuery.class` context.

Comment: Do you have RMI service running on rmi://127.0.0.1:1199/searchService ?  If RMI is ok, than maybe problem in `SearchService` implementation

Comment: @user1516873, thanks for replies, I've found the answer. `NullPointerException` had been caused by Autowiring on dynamically created `BasicSearchQuery` instance. The trick was about using `@Configurable`on `BasicSearchQuery` to avoid that.